# BufNewFile doesn't work from ftplugin

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have below autocmd in my `cobol.vim` ftplugin file in `~/.vim/ftplugin/`

```
augroup cobmods
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile * call s:CleanStart()
augroup END
```

This doesn't work when I open a file using vim filename.cob.

However, if I put the same in my .vimrc, it works.

Anybody with any insights on how I can change this autocmd to work from `cobol.vim` as I really don't want to put cobol related mods in vimrc.

Also looks like, by the time program (vim) flow reaches cobol.vim, `BufNewFile` event is no longer valid.

Comment: Your last sentence is correct. BTW: what exactly you want the function `s:CleanStart()` to be doing?

Comment: Whenever I open an empty (new) cobol file, CleanStart would create a skeleton of cobol program.

Comment: In that case, the BufNewFile triggers to late (because it will be only defined after initially the FileType event for cobol has been triggered and by that time the BufNewFile event has already been triggered). So I would create a similar autocommand in my vimrc with something like `BufNewFile *.cobol :call CobolStart()`

Comment: I don't want to put any cobol related mods in vimrc, so I modified my function CleanStart to include `if !empty(glob(fnameescape(expand('%:p'))))` condition and changed to autocmd to `VimEnter *.COB` and now it works as expected. Although I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was already diagnosed in the comments, and your current solution won't work if you try to start editing a file from within vim. If that's a problem, try this:

```
" This goes directly in ~/.vim/ftplugin/cobol.vim - no autocommands needed
if line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == ''
  call s:CleanStart()
endif
```

(I tried adding this as a comment but I can't format newlines in comments as far as I know)